# C++ процесс завершает работу с кодом -1073740791

Tags: c++, visual-c++, ввод, scanf

```cpp
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdafx.h"

int main(void)
{
    char p1[9];
    char p2[9];
    char p3[9];
    char t1[9];
    char t2[9];
    char t3[9];
    int c1;
    int c2;
    int c3;
    int r1;
    int r2;
    int r3;

    printf("Vvedite: Processor, Castoty, Ram, i Tip\n");
    scanf_s("%s %d %d %s", p1, &r1, &c1, t1);
    printf("Vvedite: Processor, Castoty, Ram, i Tip\n");
    scanf_s("%s %d %d %s", p2, &r2, &c2, t2);
    printf("Vvedite: Processor, Castoty, Ram, i Tip\n");
    scanf_s("%s %d %d %s", p3, &r3, &c3, t3);


    printf("-------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("|Charakteristiki PEVM                                       |\n");
    printf("|-----------------------------------------------------------|\n");
    printf("|Processor   |Chastota(mgz)   |RAM(mb)      |Tip            |\n");
    printf("|-----------------------------------------------------------|\n");
    printf("|            |                |             |               |\n");
    printf("|-----------------------------------------------------------|\n");
    printf("|            |                |             |               |\n");
    printf("|-----------------------------------------------------------|\n");
    printf("|            |                |             |               |\n");
    printf("|-----------------------------------------------------------|\n");
    return 0;
}
```

После запуска без отладки выполняет первую строку и просит ввести данные и завершает программу c кодом -1073740791.

[image: Консоль после выполнения части программы]

Comment: а откуда  scanf_s узнает размер массмва, чтобы инициализировать ег? Передайте размер массива тоже

Comment: А множественные предупреждения компилятора не насторожили?

Comment: Думаете, `scanf_s` от `scanf` только названием отличается? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Укажите размеры массивов:

```
printf("Vvedite: Processor, Castoty, Ram, i Tip\n");
scanf_s("%s %d %d %s", p1, 9, &r1, &c1, t1, 9);
printf("Vvedite: Processor, Castoty, Ram, i Tip\n");
scanf_s("%s %d %d %s", p2, 9, &r2, &c2, t2, 9);
printf("Vvedite: Processor, Castoty, Ram, i Tip\n");
scanf_s("%s %d %d %s", p3, 9, &r3, &c3, t3, 9);
```